# Cannot save a remote image with node.js and request

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I want to save an image with node.js and the [request library](https://github.com/request/request). So far I have this simple code:

```
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');

request('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8c/JPEG_example_JPG_RIP_025.jpg', function(error, response, body)
{
    // further logic that decides
    // whether or not the image will be saved

    fs.writeFile('downloaded.jpg', body, function(){});
});
```

But it doesn't work. The image always arrives corrupt. I assume it's an encoding error but I cannot figure out how to fix this.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
var request = require('request'), 
    fs      = require('fs'),
    url     = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8c/JPEG_example_JPG_RIP_025.jpg';

request(url, {encoding: 'binary'}, function(error, response, body) {
  fs.writeFile('downloaded.jpg', body, 'binary', function (err) {});
});
```

Answer (score 5):

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    request = require('request'),
    url='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8c/JPEG_example_JPG_RIP_025.jpg';

request(url).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('downloaded.jpg'));
```

Comment: I've seen examples on the request page using the streaming variant. While this generally works I need the variant that is using the callback because I have some further logic running that decides whether or not the image will be saved. But thx for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I did it using `stream` and `pipe`, (I was using `express` but you may not need that)

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var filesystem = require('fs');
var https = require('https');


var download = function(url, dest, cb) {
   var file = filesystem.createWriteStream(dest);
   var request = https.get(url, function(httpResponse) {
    httpResponse.pipe(file);
    file.on('finish', function() {
      console.log("piping to file finished")
      file.close(cb);  // close() is async, call cb after close completes.
    });
   }).on('error', function(err) { // Handle errors
    filesystem.unlink(dest); // Delete the file async. (But we don't check the result)
    if (cb) cb(err.message);
   });
};

app.get('/image', (req, res) => {
 download('https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/15cc734fb0e045e3baac02674d2092d6.png',
          'porcupine.png', 
           () => {console.log("downloaded to porcupine.png")})
})
```

When I run using `node server.js` and hit the url `localhost:3000/image`, it will download and save the file to `porcupine.png` in the base directory.

Comment: That's a lot of things I did not ask for, but I'm sure this will be helpful for someone. Thanks for sharing!